# undefined reference to `Action_user::Slot()'

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator

Ubuntu 16.04 Qt 5.6 Creator 3.6.1 
Пробовал с Qt 5.3, удалял объектные файлы, перекомпилировал.

Автоматически сгенерированный код.

```
void Action_user::qt_static_metacall(QObject *_o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)
{
    if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
        Action_user *_t = static_cast<Action_user *>(_o);
        Q_UNUSED(_t)
        switch (_id) {
        case 0: _t->RegistrationSignal(); break;
        case 1: _t->RegistrationSlot(); break; // ОШИБКА ЗДЕСЬ
        default: ;
        }
    } else if (_c == QMetaObject::IndexOfMethod) {
        int *result = reinterpret_cast<int *>(_a[0]);
        void **func = reinterpret_cast<void **>(_a[1]);
        {
            typedef void (Action_user::*_t)();
            if (*reinterpret_cast<_t *>(func) == static_cast<_t>(&Action_user::RegistrationSignal)) {
                *result = 0;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    Q_UNUSED(_a);
}
```

Ошибка:

```
/moc_action_user.cpp:78: error: undefined reference to `Action_user::RegistrationSlot()'
```

Мои исходники:

```
// action_user.cpp
#include "action_user.h"
Action_user::Action_user(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

void Action_user::Action_route(int route)
{
  connect(this, SIGNAL(RegistrationSignal()), this, SLOT(RegistrationSlot()));
  switch (route) {
    case 1:  emit RegistrationSignal(); break;
    default:
      break;
    }
}

#ifndef ACTION_USER_H
#define ACTION_USER_H

#include <QByteArray>
#include "cargo.h"

class Action_user : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Action_user(QObject *parent = 0);
  void Action_route(int);

signals:
  void RegistrationSignal();

private slots:
  void RegistrationSlot();

private:
  int route_signal;


};

#endif // ACTION_USER_H
```

Comment: `RegistrationSlot` должен быть со скобками здесь: `connect(this, SIGNAL(RegistrationSignal()), this, SLOT(RegistrationSlot));`

Comment: исправил, но не помогло

Comment: Ну а теперь смотрите в коде, есть ли где реализация `RegistrationSlot()` и почему её не видит компилятор.

Comment: Благодарю, за подсказки. Заработало. В следующий раз буду внимательней.

Comment: У вас происходит соединение сигнала со слотом при каждом вызове функции `Action_route(int)`. Получается множественное соединение, и при вызове сигнала `RegistrationSignal()` слот `RegistrationSlot()` будет вызываться столько же раз, сколько зарегистрировано соединений. Вряд ли здесь вы хотели именно этого. Чтобы избавиться перенесите `connect(this, SIGNAL(RegistrationSignal()), this, SLOT(RegistrationSlot()));` в конструктор.

Comment: И вообще подумайте, нужны ли вам здесь сигналы-слоты?

Comment: Вопервых хочу усвоить работу с сигналами-слотами, во вторых планирую запускать в многопоточном режиме.

Comment: Оформите пожалуйста ответ, я его зачту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegistrationSlot должен быть со скобками здесь: connect(this, SIGNAL(RegistrationSignal()), this, SLOT(RegistrationSlot));

Ну а теперь смотрите в коде, есть ли где реализация RegistrationSlot() и почему её не видит компилятор.

У вас происходит соединение сигнала со слотом при каждом вызове функции Action_route(int). Получается множественное соединение, и при вызове сигнала RegistrationSignal() слот RegistrationSlot() будет вызываться столько же раз, сколько зарегистрировано соединений. Вряд ли здесь вы хотели именно этого. Чтобы избавиться перенесите connect(this, SIGNAL(RegistrationSignal()), this, SLOT(RegistrationSlot())); в конструктор.

спасибо @alexis031182